# Pointer within struct to dynamic array of structures C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-management, struct

I am confused with one of the usual issues in C which is memory management and pointers. I have three structs, like this.

```
typedef struct {
   uint8_t  uuid[16];
} uuid_array;

typedef struct Detail {
   int8_t power;
   uint32_t t1;
   uint32_t dT;
} Detail_t;

typedef struct Base {
   uuid_array unique_id;
   Detail_t *data;
} Base_t;
```

I would like to create ten `Base_t` structs and I want the `data` pointer in each `Base_t` `struct` to point to an array of dynamically growing `Detail_t` structs.

I know I should use `malloc()`, and `realloc()` but I have no experience using these functions and I am quite confused as to how they work.

How can the `data` pointer point to a dynamically sized array of `Detail_t` `struct`s?

Thank you very much.

Comment: After [reading the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Any C textbook or tutorial should explain how to use `malloc` and `realloc` to implement a dynamic array. It's no different when the pointer is in a `struct`.

Comment: In `struct Base` you will want to add an item `int n_dataItems` to keep track of how many items there are in your array.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Where and how do I declare the detail_t array however, in order to link it to the "data" pointer of the base structure.

Comment: Perhaps consider [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: you should define in struct Base_t the pointer to Detail_t array as:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
   {
   uint8_t  uuid[16];
   } uuid_array;

typedef struct Detail
   {
   int8_t   power;
   uint32_t t1;
   uint32_t dT;
   } Detail_t;

typedef struct Base
   {
   uuid_array  unique_id;
   Detail_t   *data;
   uint32_t    dataItemCnt;  /* In struct Base you will want to add an item int **
                           ** n_dataItems to keep track of how many items     **
                           ** there are in your array. – Paul Ogilvie         */
   } Base_t;

#define SUCCESS 0

/**********************************************************
** Append a Detail_t structure to the data field of the to Base_t structure..
*/
int AppendData(Base_t *baseT, int8_t power, uint32_t t1, uint32_t dT)
   {
   int rCode = SUCCESS;
   Detail_t *data=NULL;

   /* Verify that the caller did not pass NULL as the Base_t structure address. */
   if(!baseT)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;     /* Invalid Base_t value argument. */
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

  /* Increase the size of the baseT->data array sufficient for an additional Detail_t structure. */
   errno=SUCCESS;
   data=realloc(baseT->data, (baseT->dataItemCnt + 1) * sizeof(Detail_t));
   if(!data)  /* Verify that the realloc() succeeded. */
      {
      rCode=errno;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Cause the Base_t data array to point to the newly (re-alloced) memory. */
   baseT->data = data; 

   /* Initialize the new Detail_t structure values. */
   baseT->data[baseT->dataItemCnt].power = power;
   baseT->data[baseT->dataItemCnt].t1    = t1;
   baseT->data[baseT->dataItemCnt].dT    = dT;

   /* Increment Base_t->dataItemCnt to reflect the appended Detail_t structure. */
   ++baseT->dataItemCnt;

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

/**********************************************************
** Free a previously allocated Base_t type.
*/
int FreeBaseT(Base_t **baseT)
   {
   int rCode = SUCCESS;

   /* Verify that the caller did not pass in NULL for baseT */
   if(!baseT)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;     /* Invalid Base_t value argument. */
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* verify that the the Base_t structure is not already free. */
   if(!*baseT)
      {
      rCode=EALREADY;   /* The Base_t structure is NULL  (Already free). */
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* If there are Detail_t structures in the data array, free the data array. */
   if((*baseT)->data)
      free((*baseT)->data);

   /* Free the memory previously allocated to the Base_t structure. */
   free(*baseT);
   *baseT = NULL;   /* Eliminate the caller's reference to the freed memory. */

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

/**********************************************************
** Allocate a Base_t type.
*/
int AllocBaseT(Base_t **baseT_OUT, uint8_t uuid[16])
   {
   int     rCode = SUCCESS;
   Base_t *baseT = NULL;

   /* Allocate memory to the Base_t structure. */
   errno=SUCCESS;
   baseT = malloc(sizeof(Base_t));
   if(!baseT)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Initialize the initial values of the Base_t structure. */
   memset(baseT, 0, sizeof(Base_t));
   memcpy(&baseT->unique_id.uuid, uuid, 16);

   /* Ensure that the caller passed a non-NULL address,
      if so, return the address of the allocated Base_t structure. */
   if(baseT_OUT)
      {
      *baseT_OUT = baseT;
      baseT = NULL;
      }

CLEANUP:

   /* If the caller passed-in a NULL for baseT_OUT,
      free the allocated memory to that the program does not cause a leak. */
   if(baseT)
      {
      int rc=FreeBaseT(&baseT);
      if(rc && !rCode)
         rCode=rc;
      }

   return(rCode);
   }

/**********************************************************
** Dump a base_t structure.
*/
int DumpBaseT(Base_t *baseT)
   {
   int      rCode   = SUCCESS;
   uint32_t index;

   if(!baseT)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;     /* Invalid Base_t value argument. */
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Print the Base_t->unique_array->uuid */
   printf("UUID: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n",
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[0],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[1],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[2],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[3],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[4],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[5],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[6],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[7],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[8],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[9],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[10],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[11],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[12],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[13],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[14],
      baseT->unique_id.uuid[15]
      );

   /* Print the Base_t->Detail_t values */   
   printf("Number of data items: %u\n",  baseT->dataItemCnt);
   for(index=0; index < baseT->dataItemCnt; ++index)
      {
      printf("   data[%d] power=%d t1=%d dT=%d\n",
         index,
         baseT->data[index].power,
         baseT->data[index].t1,
         baseT->data[index].dT
         );
      }

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

/**********************************************************
** Program start.
*/
int main(int argC, char *argV[])
   {
   int     rCode   = SUCCESS;
   Base_t *baset_A = NULL;
   uint8_t  uuid[16] =
      {
      0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
      0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10
      };

   /* Allocate memory for a Base_t structure (with no attached data) */
   rCode=AllocBaseT(&baset_A, uuid);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "AllocBaseT() reports: %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Allocate some data (Detail_t) to the Base_t structure. */
   rCode=AppendData(baset_A, 1, 1000, 1111);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "AppendData() reports: %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   rCode=AppendData(baset_A, 2, 2000, 2222);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "AppendData() reports: %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   rCode=AppendData(baset_A, 3, 3000, 3333);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "AppendData() reports: %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Print out the Base_t structure. */
   rCode=DumpBaseT(baset_A);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "DumpBaseT() reports: %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

CLEANUP:

   /* Free the memory allocated to the Base_t structure. */ 
   if(baset_A)
      {
      int rc=FreeBaseT(&baset_A);
      if(rc)
         fprintf(stderr, "FreeBaseT() reports: %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      }

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Output:

```
UUID: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10
Number of data items: 3
   data[0] power=1 t1=1000 dT=1111
   data[1] power=2 t1=2000 dT=2222
   data[2] power=3 t1=3000 dT=3333
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short code to showcase how you could go about it:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   uint8_t  uuid[16];
} uuid_array;

typedef struct Detail {
   int8_t power;
   uint32_t t1;
   uint32_t dT;
} Detail_t;

typedef struct Base {
   uuid_array unique_id;
   Detail_t *data;
} Base_t;


int main() {
  Detail_t data;
  data.power = data.t1 = data.dT = 1;
  Detail_t data2;
  data2.power = data2.t1 = data2.dT = 2;
  Base_t bases[10];//array of Base_t
  int size = 1;//initial size of Detail_t array
  bases[0].data = NULL;
  bases[0].data = (Detail_t* )realloc(bases[0].data, size * sizeof(Detail_t));//first realloc acts as a malloc because bases[0].data is NULL at first
  if (bases[0].data != NULL) {//if malloc(realloc) was successful
    bases[0].data[0] = data;//store data
  }
  size = 2;//increase size of Detail_t array by 1
  bases[0].data = (Detail_t* )realloc(bases[0].data, size * sizeof(Detail_t));//realloc new size
  if (bases[0].data != NULL) {//if it didn't fail
    bases[0].data[1] = data2;//store new data
  }
  printf("%d\n", bases[0].data[0].power);//print first data power
  printf("%d", bases[0].data[1].power);//print second data power
  free(bases[0].data);//free memory
}
```

Does this help? I guess the part that confuses beginners is the cast. Malloc and realloc returns a pointer of type void* to the memory allocated , which you then can cast to the type you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
typedef struct Base {
   uuid_array unique_id;
   int n_dataIems;
   Detail_t *data;
} Base_t;

void example(void)
{
    Base_t t;
    int i;
    t.n_dataItems= 0;
    t.data= 0;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        t.data= realloc(t.data, ++t.n_dataItems * sizeof(Detail_t));
        t.data[i].power= i;
    }
}
```

(Error checking ommitted.)

Note: definition of Detail must be before Base.

Comment: Thanks for that, but could you maybe also quickly explain why this works? By incrementing "t" in that loop, what exactly is going on. Are you just looking at the next struct in the array?

Comment: And in my code, I would not actually know what the "4" (for loop's upper limit) will actually be. It will be dependent on the amount of BT devices that it detects. Would I need to rerun this for loop from 0 to n in main, every time that I detect a BT device, or just from previous n to current n. Thank you

Comment: the `++t.n_dataItems`  increments n_dataItems, Its just counting the added items.

Comment: Stellarhawk, you REALLY need to read a book on C if you don't understand these simple constructs and can't extend a for loop to a while loop. And read a book on programming in general. I hope you will not write production code.